# Single edge defraction on a concave screen

Tags: optics, visible-light, diffraction

I was doing research on single/straight edge  fringe patterns. I can always find an image on a flat screen but I have not found one on a concave screen that matches a radius from the edge. Could anyone guide me in the right direction?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you explain your problem more clearly? You have a diffractive screen and want to find the diffraction pattern on a curved surface rather than a flat screen?

Comment: I will send a drawing

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/82iftrk07478bjw/doc_Page_14.jpg?dl=0                     This drawing shows a typical fringe pattern from a single / straight edge onto a flat screen. The red circle represents a curved screen with a radius from the edge. What would the new image look like and has the experiment been done?

Comment: I don't have tools sensitive enough to do this experiment. And if it has never been done does anyone have a guess as to whether or not there would be a pattern and if so what would it look like compared to the original?

Comment: It certainly has a quite similar diffraction pattern. You can calculate the exact pattern by considering the shape of the screen (The integrals can get more complicated).

Comment: I have calculated it and it comes out with no pattern. That is why I am asking for verification from actual experiment.

Comment: Is the illumination a plane wave or (as depicted in the sketch) a point source?

Comment: If by illumination you mean the fringe pattern at the top of the drawing that is an actual photograph of a real single edge Fringe  pattern

Comment: If the screen is a perfect radius from the edge then the amplitude  would be consistent across the screen

Comment: I meant the wave incident on the edge. In the figure above it's a point source S. But in many diffraction problems it is assumed a plane wave.

Comment: Yes it is a point source for photons. The math is derived from there to the flat screen. The red arc represents A curved screen with equal distance back to the point. So what ever amplitude was hitting the screen would be the same all along the arc